# Assigning a value to two keys inner a array

Tags: php

At primitive variables i can assign multiple variables like:

```
$variable_1 = $variable2 = array ( '...' );
```

But how can i assign a value in a array to two keys?

```
$outer_array = array (
    'key_1' => 'key_2' => array ( '...' )
);
```

wont work. Is it possible while defining the array to assign a value to this two keys?

Comment: `$outer_array['key_1'] = $outer_array['key_2'] = $value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option if you must do this:

```
$outer_array['key_1'] = $outer_array['key_2'] = array ( '...' );
```